# Laravel 5.2 persistent session id through login, ok to use _token?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, session-variables

I need to reserve items in my database when a user adds them to his/her basket. I am currently using the session id (`Session::getId()`) however this is regenerated at login. Whilst you can shop as a guest, to checkout you must register.

If i take a look at all session variables with `$request->session()->all()` i have come across the `_token`, this looks like a unique string and it does not regenerate at login, i was therefore thinking of using this for my baskets?

Is this safe?

If not alternatively i would have to generate my own uuid's in PHP and store them as basket_id or something, this would save me having to do this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `_token` is to defend against csrf attack. More here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf

Comment: @ventaquil perfect, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I copy my comment here:

*_token* is to defend against csrf attack. More here: [laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf](http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf)

*_token* field is unique per request. You can send this token as request variable or cookie.

Remember - by default all post actions need this field (one of middlewares keep eye on this).

You have access to token value by function `csrf_token()` - or `csrf_field()` to get HTML input field.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a database driver for sessions, https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#driver-prerequisites.

Using that you can reference the session table in your reserved items table. You will know whether a user is a guest.

You can even see the last activity and base your reserved items on that.

Comment: I'll be using redis for sessions, I think i will use the basket ID approach.